# How do I output the number loops in after a while()?

Tags: java

Im trying to get the output for the number of times the loop was ran over, decided by the user. Im using `while()` but I'm not sure how to output the number of loops once the loop is over.

Here's my code:

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose a number between 2 and 10, choose 1 to end it");
        int number1 = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("You Chose Number " + number1);
        while (number1 != 1) {
           System.out.println("Choose a number between 2 and 10, choose 1 to end it");
           number1 = input.nextInt();
           System.out.println("You Chose Number " + number1);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Thank you for choosing. Goodbye");
    }       
}
```

please help me thank you !!

Comment: Create an int variable (I'll call it ``count``) before your while loop, set to zero initially. Then increase it by one inside your while loop (``count++;``). After your loop ends, it will contain the number of times through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need an additional variable that increments each time the loop occurs.  Then after the loop you can use that variable to show the number of times looped.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose a number between 2 and 10, choose 1 to end it");
    int number1 = input.nextInt();
    int loopcount = 0;
    
    System.out.println("You Chose Number " + number1);
    while (number1 != 1){
       System.out.println("Choose a number between 2 and 10, choose 1 to end it");
       number1 = input.nextInt();
       loopcount += 1;
       System.out.println("You Chose Number " + number1);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Thank you for choosing. Goodbye");
    System.out.println("Looped " + loopcount + " times";
}
```

By the way, you could also optimise the function by eliminating the input request before the "while()" loop.  It's repeated, redundant code that doesn't need to be there.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number1 = 0;
    int loopcount = -1;
    
    while (number1 != 1) {
       System.out.println("Choose a number between 2 and 10, choose 1 to end it");
       number1 = input.nextInt();
       loopcount += 1;
        System.out.println("You Chose Number " + number1);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Thank you for choosing. Goodbye");
    System.out.println("Looped " + loopcount + " times";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only requirement to **count the looping** then taking an int **variable** is enough, but if you want to **keep records the chosen number** then take a List which can store the chosen numbers dynamically and its length would be the looping count.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        int count=0;
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList(); // if chosen num is needed
        
        do{
           System.out.print("Choose a number between 2 and 10, choose 1 to end it :");
           choice = scanner.nextInt();
           if(choice !=1 ) {
             count++;
             numbers.add(choice);   // if chosen num is needed
           }
        
        }while (choice != 1);
        
        System.out.println("Loop counts " + count);
        System.out.println("Loop counts " + numbers.size() + " times and numbers are "+numbers);
    }
```

Comment: Creating a list just to maintain a count is quite wasteful.  The right thing is to just maintain a count.  A count is a few bytes of storage vs building a data structure.  Your indentation is messed up.  Finally, this is a code only answer, which is discouraged.  You should explain what the code you post is doing...how it answers the question.